# Update filter range of currently active filter

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I would need to create an onOpen() function, which reapplies the current filter settings on an updated range. I have thought of creating a loop which gets the current filter criteria (.getColumnFilterCriteria()). Then I would remove the current filter and reapply the new filter with the different column criteria.

Is there any easier way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: if you have to change the criteria, the is no simpler way than changing the criteria. I challenge your assumption that you need an `onOpen` function to do this, however. You should also ensure you are aware of the limitations imposed on simple trigger functions like it, by thoroughly reviewing the Apps Script documentation.

Comment: The filter criteria are always the same and should stay the same. The underlying problem is the filter range. Data will be added and the filter should be updated to the new range.

Comment: By using GS macro recording function, I can do exactely this. However, I need to manually set the filter criteria. I need something more generic.

Comment: Filter range will be automatically updated on addition of new row data without manual intervention

Comment: not if the data is imported via importrange